# Call C# method from js function is MasterPage

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to call MasterPage code behind C# method from javascript function (js function is in front end of MasterPage)

Comment: Can you give us an example?  My first thought is no.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the signalR library.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Answer (score 0):

Yes by using page method :

```
 function uploadPanelClear() {

    PageMethods.setSession(OnSucceededSession, OnFailedSession);

}
function OnFailedSession()
{
}
function OnSucceededSession()
{

}
```

CS :

```
  [WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
    public static string setSession()
    {

        return "";
    }
```